# Connect Biometric Device output to Open ERP 6.1

Tags: odoo, fingerprint, biometrics, hole-punching

Is it possible to Connect Biometric Device output directly to openERP?

Our company has a Biometric FingerPrint Machine and at the end of day, we have an excel sheet which contains all the attendance records of the Employees. We import this excel sheet into openERP.

But is there anyway that whenever a Employee uses their fingerprint-reader, then the record is added in openERP or database. Then we will not have to import excel sheets one by one daily.

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 4):

That needs a development on the time & attendance side, so it depends a lot on what it's software allows you to do. Usually, entry level solutions don't allow you to do a lot.

To write to OpenERP you can use a [XML-RPC call](http://doc.openerp.com/v6.0/developer/6_22_XML-RPC_web_services/index.html), or write directly to a table in OpenERPs database.

The [`import_sqlpush`](http://openerpmanagementsystem.blogspot.pt/2012/11/pushing-data-into-openerp.html) module could also be an option. I use it with [Pentaho PDI](http://www.pentaho.com/explore/pentaho-data-integration/) (aka Kettle) to schedule frequent data exchanges between OpenERP and other databases. It can even regularly check for excel files in a folder and import them if found.

Answer (score 0):

The same question has been posted at https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/is-it-possible-to-connect-biometric-device-output-directly-to-openerp-75132

As per the latest update in that post, for connecting the biometric machine with openERP directly is possible, if the device supports the WebAPI. Otherwise, you will have to develop the middleware which will read the attendance records from machine and update with openERP.